Maximum Value of $A\sin(\alpha x) + B\sin(\beta x)$
Problem Statement

For $x \in (0, \pi)$ , the equation $\sin(x)+ 2\sin(2x) -\sin(3x)$, find the maximum value of this equation?

I know how to solve this, we  take $f'(x)=0$ and proceed. However, something I am interested is in finding the maximum value of any combination of such functions, for example :

The maximum value of $A\sin(\alpha x)+B\sin(\beta x)$

This question has intrigued me a lot of times. Is there any formula, like
$$-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\leq A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)\leq \sqrt{A^2+B^2}$$

Yes, the inequalites follow from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

These are two different questions. Given an open interval $I$ and $f:I\ni x\mapsto \left(A\sin(\alpha x)+B\cos(\beta x)\right)\in\mathbb{R}$, if there's a maximum value for the function, it can be found by computing $x$ when $\frac{d}{dx}\left(A\sin(\alpha x)+B\cos(\beta x)\right)=0$. However, and independently of this question, we can find an upper (and lower) bound for such a function. Take $(A,B),(\sin(\alpha x),\cos(\beta x))$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, pick the usual norm and inner product, then $|f(x)|=|(A,B)\cdot(\sin(\alpha x),\cos(\beta x))|\leq||(A,B)||\cdot||(\sin(\alpha x),\cos(\beta x))||$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, as mentioned by someone in the comments. In particular, if $\alpha=\beta$, then $|f(x)|\leq\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\Rightarrow -\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\leq f(x)\leq\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$, since $||(\sin(\alpha x),\cos(\alpha x)||=\left(\sin^2(\alpha x)+\cos^2(\alpha x)\right)^{1/2}=1$.

Thanks. Are there any resources that I can use to further understand the use cases of the inequality?

@aditya, besides the link provided (which should be helpful, specially the "$\mathbb{R}^2$ - The plane" section, if you've never seen it before [also, maybe the wikipedia page on the dot product would be helpful, if that's the case]), I guess it depends if you've met Linear Algebra before or not. "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Axler is probably a good recommendation, if you know something about Linear Algebra already. If you don't, maybe just convince yourself of the "geometric definition" (as seen on the dot product page on the wikipedia) and the inequality should be quite direct.
